# Take Button label name to UILongPressGestureRecognizer, change var and return value to Button's label

Tags: swift, alert, long-press

Help me, please. What I try to do:
I have some var and button. When I long press the button I want the alert pop-up with text field. Then I want to put in some value (Int) and than change my button's label to (textField value + previous). And I want to write one function for several button. What I tried to do:

```
func addLongPressGesture(by sender: UIButton){
    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPress(gesture:)))
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1
    sender.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
}

@objc func longPress(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.began {
        print("Long Press")

        var textField = UITextField()
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "How much?", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (action) in

            if let howMuch = textField.text {
                self.VARIABLE1 = self.VARIABBLE1 + Int(howMuch)!
                self.viewWillAppear(true)
            }
        }
        alert.addAction(action)
        alert.addTextField { (alertTextField) in
            textField = alertTextField
            textField.placeholder = "How much?"
        }
           present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I want VARIABLE1 changes depending on what button I long press

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have declared multiple variables, one for each button. This is a good sign that you should start using arrays. Declare one array instead of your multiple variables:

```
var totals = Array(repeating: 0, count: <however many buttons you have>)
```

Then, give each of your buttons a different [`tag`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622493-tag). You can also set this in the storyboard. The first button will have tag 0, the second button will have tag 1, and so on.

In `longPress`, get the button that was clicked with `gesture.view`, and get the tag. The tag is the index of the array that you should increment:

```
if let howMuch = textField.text {
    self.totals[gesture.view!.tag] += Int(howMuch)! // Note: you should probably unwrap the Int? safely
    self.viewWillAppear(true) // Note: you shouldn't really call this yourself
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  `gesture.view!.tag` is what I look for!